# 文章の組み合わせを算出するプログラム

Tags: python

```
sample = "私は<アイスクリーム|アイスキャンデー|アイス>が好き(なの)です。"
```

とします。

1. `<>`に囲まれた部分は、どれでもいいが、線で区切られた単語のうち、この中のどれか一つは書かれていなければならないとします。
2. `()`に囲まれた文字は、あってもなくても構わないとします。

このとき、1と2を満たす組み合わせとなる文を作りたいと思っています。
まず、どれか3つのうちで3通り。`（）`はあるかないかで2通り。
計6通りの文章が出来上がると思います。
この6通りを瞬時に算出するプログラムを書きたいのですが、
どうすればいいでしょうか。なんなら、`<>`などは別の記号に置き換えても
もちろん問題ありません。
  　　
　環境: python3.6

Comment: タイトルと本文とで質問内容が一致していないように見えます。ルールに従った定義になっているかの「判定」をしたいのか、ルールに従った定義から「文章を出力したい」のかがはっかりしません。また、断片でも構わないのでご自身で書かれたコードも一緒に提示してあると回答が付きやすいと思います。

Comment: 質問の編集を行うと自動的に更新リストの上部に来ます。タグやノイズとなるような情報はタイトルに含めないでください。また、解決済みとした後に追加の質問が出た場合は新しく質問を立てることをオススメします。

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### 単語候補リストの作成

まずは、`< | >` や `( )` といった記号を用いた独自の記法をパースして、文を構成する単語の候補になるリストたちを作成します。（パース部分に関しては、この回答では扱いません）

- 必須:
  「`私は`」のように何にも囲まれていない出現が必須の単語。
  これは要素数1の単語候補リストになります。
  リスト表現: `["私は"]`
- 選択:
  「`<アイスクリーム|アイスキャンデー|アイス>`」のように `< >` で囲まれた、どれかを選択する単語たち。
  これはそのまま、単語候補リストになります。
  リスト表現: `["アイスクリーム", "アイスキャンデー", "アイス"]`
- 任意:
  「`(なの)`」のように `( )` で囲まれた、有っても無くてもよい単語。
  これは空文字とこの単語とを選択させる `<なの|>` と同義ですから、2要素の単語候補リストになります。
  リスト表現: `["なの", ""]`
- 任意単語を含む選択:
  「`<>`の中にも`()`のあるパターン」というのは、たとえば `<(なの)|なのかも知れない>` のようなものだと思いますが、これは選択に空文字を含めた `<なの||なのかも知れない>` と同義です。
  リスト表現: `["なの", "", "なのかも知れない"]`

これにより独自記法の、

```
"私は<アイスクリーム|アイスキャンデー|アイス>が好き(なの)です。"
```

は5つのリスト、

```
["私は"],
["アイスクリーム", "アイスキャンデー", "アイス"],
["が好き"],
["なの", ""],
["です。"],
```

となります。

#### 組み合わせ

目的はおそらく、単語候補リストのいわゆる「直積」を求めることです。
「直積 アルゴリズム」などでWebを検索すると解説があると思いますが、以下では [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.jp/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) をそのまま使っています。
（`return` で返しているのは内包表記で生成したイテレータです。解り難ければループなどに展開して理解して下さい）

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import itertools

def gen_sentences(*word_lists):
    return ("".join(words) for words in itertools.product(*word_lists))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    sentences = gen_sentences(
        ["私は"],
        ["アイスクリーム", "アイスキャンデー", "アイス"],
        ["が好き"],
        ["なの", ""],
        ["です。"],
    )
    for s in sentences:
        print(s)
```

出力:

```
私はアイスクリームが好きなのです。
私はアイスクリームが好きです。
私はアイスキャンデーが好きなのです。
私はアイスキャンデーが好きです。
私はアイスが好きなのです。
私はアイスが好きです。
```