# リストの中身をそのまま引数とする方法

Tags: python

連投になります。[前の質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/40343/19110)と関連していることなのですが、
`[[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2]]`のようなリストがあったとして、
これを、`itertools.product(*iterables)`に入れる。
このままだと、`[0,1,2]`と`[0,1,2]`は別別にいれなければ
ならない、あるいは私はこの方法しか知りません。

このままだと、2つだから、インデックスを2つ指定すれば
いいんじゃないかと思われるかもしれませんが、例えば、
上のリストがどのような内容であっても、同様に行いたい。
事前にリストの長さはわからないものとします。

一気にすべての要素を引数に入れたいのですが、
そのような方法は可能でしょうか？

環境: python 3.6.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

以下のように書けます

```
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.product([0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2]))
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]

>>> list(itertools.product(*[[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2]]))
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]

>>> iterables = [[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2]]
>>> list(itertools.product(*iterables))
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
```

`*` の使い方は以下のドキュメントにあります。
https://docs.python.org/ja/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists

Comment: できました。感激！とても助かりました。一回チェックつけた後すぐ消してしまいましたが、再度また点灯させました。もし気付いていたら申し訳ありませんでした。